# Any way to set user role permissions in the site editor?

Tags: block-editor, user-roles, editor, permissions, full-site-editing

Is there any way to set specific permissions in the site editor for user roles? I have a block theme and want to give editor roles the permissions to edit templates, but not to add or delete them. I also want to hide the Styles menu. Is it possible?

[image]